# gcc: mixing -Wformat and register_printf_specifier

Tags: c++, c, gcc, printf

I would like to use custom printf format flags (via gcc's `register_printf_specifier`) while still reaping the benefits of `-Wformat` and `-Werror` compiler flags.

In the below example I have managed to print my widget using a custom `%W` flag, but I have to disable `-Wformat` and `-Wformat-extra-args`

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-extra-args"
```

Is is possible to have the best of both worlds?

I suppose my question boils down to: Is there a way to register a format specifier and associated type with `-Wformat`?

### Example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <printf.h>

struct Widget
{
    const char* name;
};

int print_widget(FILE* stream, const struct printf_info* info, const void* const* args)
{
    const Widget* widget = *((const Widget**)(args[0]));
    return fprintf(stream, "%*s", (info->left ? -info->width : info->width), widget->name);
}

int print_widget_arginfo(const struct printf_info*, size_t n, int* argtypes, int* size)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        argtypes[0] = PA_POINTER;
        size[0] = sizeof (Widget *);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    register_printf_specifier('W', print_widget, print_widget_arginfo);

    Widget widget { "foobar" };

    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-extra-args"

    printf("|%W|\n", &widget);
    printf("|%35W|\n", &widget);
    printf("|%-35W|\n", &widget);
}
```

### Output:

```
|foobar|
|                             foobar|
|foobar                             |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no such way.  See [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47781).

It isn't *too* hard to modify GCC to expose some of its internal machinery for `printf` checking, making it possible to write a GCC plugin that understands your additions.  It does require a bit of familiarity with GCC though.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no direct way to register new specifiers against `-Wformat`, there is a kind of workaround. You can overload `%p` itself and detect if it is supposed to be a `Widget*`. One way to do that would be to encode a special value into the width, and let your specifier code detect the special value. For example,

```
#define IS_WIDGET(INFO) (((INFO)->width & MASK) == WIDGET)

int print_widget(FILE* stream, const struct printf_info* info,
                 const void* const* args)
{
    if (IS_WIDGET(info)) return print_widget_impl(stream, info, args);
    return fprintf(stream, "%#*llx",
                   (info->left ? -info->width : info->width),
                   (unsigned long long)*(void **)args[0]);
}
```

A proof of concept can be found [here](https://tio.run/##rVRdb9MwFH3Pr7hKtWFHDcs07YXSommsWwVs1VZUJEBWljippdaJbJcVtv51ih07bUorpkn4IYnvx7n3HN84KcswT5LVqsV4Mp2nFN4mUqWs6Hnblim7b5pMDFevJ01bKbQpMzavldKMcQrD2xEZjm7Jp7O7DxB96fcjvdbe8eD95cUIosVxtMdO9Gt0hcYYEIoWfb3gENCcS5ZzmoKcFEJh7cbwBMimYNzEGF2Rmz6xHjS47t9oJAv0uYmErS/sPbBUTTYIg7u/ctFWoIZossPQ7brGsedJJeaJgjFLc6q8Rw/0SgouFSSTWATA4xnteMuO52nJoBKOPFTBhM3KKeoPPl4EoFFoPGu7TIdpVSaMZ0UA5ln7fxQsDex3ALHIJd4qbHsJwJaBLgQIbXkCjEzW1@g7xp0q0fRmuXZ39DSVXZigai44ZLYzVHftHwTSb0MVGfamNFPwDkKL98bi4rZrJ@wZRTTecleR/ysGywBtTrZigWsGu@dQF7XQFc4znFvBdLHL2u5q7o2dVgDNNUSpBFE4QKZv0EdRn8ReRYj2Ggz0nBaS/aJEATcErA7qZ0ml2xpvUxYOPYhwtbVGs@oc3YyeguEZGd4MrkcXt511hIGxXvNVZI4D3kTs03zt3AthR3INsmxqfrzWZBYzXlWrWQiaM6moIE4LWdKEZYwK9Kp81d7SsL1XUV2vAnL13b/yCH5WFPex8GHpAo6OWqWI81kMl@fnkLI454VULAF9pRRCX09@OM4KMYuV/8L4kC6UiEMzAL6t5WbMfzoIyqdvXE/X1gUZ6Rk6tJ06uZ5JODn9R0b48pSTU5eyCViuVr@TbBrnchWOqRCFWNX8/gA).